# .libpath different in conda env vs. base

Tags: r, anaconda, conda, mamba

I have a conda environment set up and I'm struggling to get a package called r-harp installed. One of the things I'm exploring is the path where they are looking for libraries.

My libpath in my base computer looks like this:

`> .libPaths() [1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library"`

This matches what I have in my .Renviron

However, I also have a conda environment set up called renv - when I check the .libpath in that environment, it looks like this:

`> .libPaths() [1] "/Users/priyapatel/anaconda3/envs/renv/lib/R/library"`

Where is it getting this path from / where is it being set? Where can I find that .Renviron file? I would like to modify it.

Comment: How did you create the conda environment in the first place? Does it happen if you create a new environment? It's hard to guess all the possible places where that value could have been changed. It would be easier to help with some sort of reproducible example/environment. The `?Startup` help page in R lists all the locations R will check for an .Renviron file.

Comment: I used mamba install -c conda-forge r-base